Bootstrap 5 Dropdown is Not Toggling back
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Custom Admin Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown dropdown-center">
      <button class="btn btn-outline dropdown-toggle rounded-3" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">  Order Status </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a class="dropdown-item active" href="#">In Stock</a></li>
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cancelled</a></li>
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delivered</a></li>
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Progress</a></li>
       </ul>
 </div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</body>

My Bootstrap 5 dropdown is not collapsing back, I tried so much but can't find the solution

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You're loading Bootstrap script twice, which is causing conflict.
Remove extra script tag:
    <head>
        <!-- remove this -->    
        <!--<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body>

    
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    </body>

